No puedo iniciar mi primer proyecto de angular
[Aqui esta la foto del cmd como administrador, tambien lo intente en powershell y como usuario]
Segui paso a paso la documentacion y un video tutorial de angular 18 para poder iniciar con un proyecto pero no puedo crear el archivo para poder iniciar
Podrian ayudarme a poder solucionar esto? decirme si me falta algo o que estoy haciendo mal para iniciar?

No sera por que estas intentando crear el proyecto en System32 y alli necesitas permisos de admin.

intente sin administrador y con administrador, usando Desktop para crear pero aun asi no me permite
